# How to get value from JSON Array using jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I can get all values from JSON array and also checking console. but no errors although i could't append to the table using jquery. could you please mention what is the error and how to solve this issue.

I have tried many answers for this, like: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp for JSON array using jQuery but they don't solve my problem.

html code:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
</head>
<body>
<table id="example " class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tbody"></tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({    
            type:"POST",
            url:"http://localhost/brand%20website/array.json",                      
            success:function(cal){
            console.log(cal);
            test(cal);
            }

        });
        });



        function test(data) {
    var count = 1;
    var htmlOutput = "";
    for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        htmlOutput+="<tr>";
        htmlOutput += "<td class='id' align='center'>" + (data.data[i][0] != null ? data.data[i][0] : '') + "</td>";
        htmlOutput += "<td class='company-id' align='center'>" + (data[i][1] != null ? data[i][1] : '') + "</td>";
        htmlOutput += "<td><p class='contact-name'>" + (data[i][2] != null ? data[i][2] : '') + "</p></td>";
        htmlOutput += "<td><p class='address-type'>" + (data[i][3] != null ? data[i][3] : '') + "</p></td>";
        htmlOutput += "<td><p class='address'>" + (data[i][4] != null ? data[i][4] : '') + "</p></td>";
        htmlOutput += "<td><p class='contact-number'>" + (data[i][5] != null ? data[i][5] : '') + "</p></td>";

        htmlOutput += "</tr>";
        count ++;

    }

    $(".tbody").html(htmlOutput);

}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

JSON array:

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "System Architect",
      "Edinburgh",
      "5421",
      "2011/04/25",
      "$320,800"
    ],
    [
      "Garrett Winters",
      "Accountant",
      "Tokyo",
      "8422",
      "2011/07/25",
      "$170,750"
    ],
    [
      "Ashton Cox",
      "Junior Technical Author",
      "San Francisco",
      "1562",
      "2009/01/12",
      "$86,000"
    ],
    [
      "Cedric Kelly",
      "Senior Javascript Developer",
      "Edinburgh",
      "6224",
      "2012/03/29",
      "$433,060"
    ],
    [
      "Airi Satou",
      "Accountant",
      "Tokyo",
      "5407",
      "2008/11/28",
      "$162,700"
    ],
    [
      "Brielle Williamson",
      "Integration Specialist",
      "New York",
      "4804",
      "2012/12/02",
      "$372,000"
    ],
    [
      "Herrod Chandler",
      "Sales Assistant",
      "San Francisco",
      "9608",
      "2012/08/06",
      "$137,500"
    ],
    [
      "Rhona Davidson",
      "Integration Specialist",
      "Tokyo",
      "6200",
      "2010/10/14",
      "$327,900"
    ],
    [
      "Colleen Hurst",
      "Javascript Developer",
      "San Francisco",
      "2360",
      "2009/09/15",
      "$205,500"
    ],
    [
      "Sonya Frost",
      "Software Engineer",
      "Edinburgh",
      "1667",
      "2008/12/13",
      "$103,600"
    ],
    [
      "Jena Gaines",
      "Office Manager",
      "London",
      "3814",
      "2008/12/19",
      "$90,560"
    ],
    [
      "Quinn Flynn",
      "Support Lead",
      "Edinburgh",
      "9497",
      "2013/03/03",
      "$342,000"
    ],
    [
      "Charde Marshall",
      "Regional Director",
      "San Francisco",
      "6741",
      "2008/10/16",
      "$470,600"
    ],
    [
      "Haley Kennedy",
      "Senior Marketing Designer",
      "London",
      "3597",
      "2012/12/18",
      "$313,500"
    ],
    [
      "Tatyana Fitzpatrick",
      "Regional Director",
      "London",
      "1965",
      "2010/03/17",
      "$385,750"
    ],
    [
      "Michael Silva",
      "Marketing Designer",
      "London",
      "1581",
      "2012/11/27",
      "$198,500"
    ],
    [
      "Paul Byrd",
      "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)",
      "New York",
      "3059",
      "2010/06/09",
      "$725,000"
    ],
    [
      "Gloria Little",
      "Systems Administrator",
      "New York",
      "1721",
      "2009/04/10",
      "$237,500"
    ],
    [
      "Bradley Greer",
      "Software Engineer",
      "London",
      "2558",
      "2012/10/13",
      "$132,000"
    ],
    [
      "Dai Rios",
      "Personnel Lead",
      "Edinburgh",
      "2290",
      "2012/09/26",
      "$217,500"
    ],
    [
      "Jenette Caldwell",
      "Development Lead",
      "New York",
      "1937",
      "2011/09/03",
      "$345,000"
    ],
    [
      "Yuri Berry",
      "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)",
      "New York",
      "6154",
      "2009/06/25",
      "$675,000"
    ],
    [
      "Caesar Vance",
      "Pre-Sales Support",
      "New York",
      "8330",
      "2011/12/12",
      "$106,450"
    ],
    [
      "Doris Wilder",
      "Sales Assistant",
      "Sydney",
      "3023",
      "2010/09/20",
      "$85,600"
    ],
    [
      "Angelica Ramos",
      "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
      "London",
      "5797",
      "2009/10/09",
      "$1,200,000"
    ],
    [
      "Gavin Joyce",
      "Developer",
      "Edinburgh",
      "8822",
      "2010/12/22",
      "$92,575"
    ],
    [
      "Jennifer Chang",
      "Regional Director",
      "Singapore",
      "9239",
      "2010/11/14",
      "$357,650"
    ],
    [
      "Brenden Wagner",
      "Software Engineer",
      "San Francisco",
      "1314",
      "2011/06/07",
      "$206,850"
    ],
    [
      "Fiona Green",
      "Chief Operating Officer (COO)",
      "San Francisco",
      "2947",
      "2010/03/11",
      "$850,000"
    ],
    [
      "Shou Itou",
      "Regional Marketing",
      "Tokyo",
      "8899",
      "2011/08/14",
      "$163,000"
    ],
    [
      "Michelle House",
      "Integration Specialist",
      "Sydney",
      "2769",
      "2011/06/02",
      "$95,400"
    ],
    [
      "Suki Burks",
      "Developer",
      "London",
      "6832",
      "2009/10/22",
      "$114,500"
    ],
    [
      "Prescott Bartlett",
      "Technical Author",
      "London",
      "3606",
      "2011/05/07",
      "$145,000"
    ],
    [
      "Gavin Cortez",
      "Team Leader",
      "San Francisco",
      "2860",
      "2008/10/26",
      "$235,500"
    ],
    [
      "Martena Mccray",
      "Post-Sales support",
      "Edinburgh",
      "8240",
      "2011/03/09",
      "$324,050"
    ],
    [
      "Unity Butler",
      "Marketing Designer",
      "San Francisco",
      "5384",
      "2009/12/09",
      "$85,675"
    ],
    [
      "Howard Hatfield",
      "Office Manager",
      "San Francisco",
      "7031",
      "2008/12/16",
      "$164,500"
    ],
    [
      "Hope Fuentes",
      "Secretary",
      "San Francisco",
      "6318",
      "2010/02/12",
      "$109,850"
    ],
    [
      "Vivian Harrell",
      "Financial Controller",
      "San Francisco",
      "9422",
      "2009/02/14",
      "$452,500"
    ],
    [
      "Timothy Mooney",
      "Office Manager",
      "London",
      "7580",
      "2008/12/11",
      "$136,200"
    ],
    [
      "Jackson Bradshaw",
      "Director",
      "New York",
      "1042",
      "2008/09/26",
      "$645,750"
    ],
    [
      "Olivia Liang",
      "Support Engineer",
      "Singapore",
      "2120",
      "2011/02/03",
      "$234,500"
    ],
    [
      "Bruno Nash",
      "Software Engineer",
      "London",
      "6222",
      "2011/05/03",
      "$163,500"
    ],
    [
      "Sakura Yamamoto",
      "Support Engineer",
      "Tokyo",
      "9383",
      "2009/08/19",
      "$139,575"
    ],
    [
      "Thor Walton",
      "Developer",
      "New York",
      "8327",
      "2013/08/11",
      "$98,540"
    ],
    [
      "Finn Camacho",
      "Support Engineer",
      "San Francisco",
      "2927",
      "2009/07/07",
      "$87,500"
    ],
    [
      "Serge Baldwin",
      "Data Coordinator",
      "Singapore",
      "8352",
      "2012/04/09",
      "$138,575"
    ],
    [
      "Zenaida Frank",
      "Software Engineer",
      "New York",
      "7439",
      "2010/01/04",
      "$125,250"
    ],
    [
      "Zorita Serrano",
      "Software Engineer",
      "San Francisco",
      "4389",
      "2012/06/01",
      "$115,000"
    ],
    [
      "Jennifer Acosta",
      "Junior Javascript Developer",
      "Edinburgh",
      "3431",
      "2013/02/01",
      "$75,650"
    ],
    [
      "Cara Stevens",
      "Sales Assistant",
      "New York",
      "3990",
      "2011/12/06",
      "$145,600"
    ],
    [
      "Hermione Butler",
      "Regional Director",
      "London",
      "1016",
      "2011/03/21",
      "$356,250"
    ],
    [
      "Lael Greer",
      "Systems Administrator",
      "London",
      "6733",
      "2009/02/27",
      "$103,500"
    ],
    [
      "Jonas Alexander",
      "Developer",
      "San Francisco",
      "8196",
      "2010/07/14",
      "$86,500"
    ],
    [
      "Shad Decker",
      "Regional Director",
      "Edinburgh",
      "6373",
      "2008/11/13",
      "$183,000"
    ],
    [
      "Michael Bruce",
      "Javascript Developer",
      "Singapore",
      "5384",
      "2011/06/27",
      "$183,000"
    ],
    [
      "Donna Snider",
      "Customer Support",
      "New York",
      "4226",
      "2011/01/25",
      "$112,000"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: i can't understand could please provide jsfiddle example

Answer (score 0):

Your response looks like this :

```
{
    "data": [ ... ]
}
```

The array is located in a member named `data`.

When calling `test()`, use `test(cal.data)` instead of `test(cal)`, so you'll pass the array directly.

```js
const cal = {
  "data": [
    [ "foo" ],
    [ "bar" ],
    [ "hello" ],
    [ "world" ]
  ]
};

function test(data) {
    for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        console.log(data[i][0])
    }
}

console.log("wrong call :");
test(cal);

console.log("---------------------------------");

console.log("good call :");
test(cal.data);
```

Comment: Glad I could help you. Did you understand what was the error ?